# How Do I Download Azure Function Logs?

Tags: java, azure-functions

I have an Azure Function written in Java that is triggered on a blob being upload to a storage container.
I am writing a Java application to manage the Function outside of the Portal.

How do I download the logs for each function run as a log file?

Answer (score 0):

There are two situations:

First, if you are based on Windows OS, then you can go to the related azure file share storage of the azure function to get the application insights(the fileshare name should be the same as your function app name).

Second, if you are based on Linux OS, then you can try to [export the application insights](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/azure/azure-monitor/app/export-telemetry).